# Having an image overlap a div and go behind text

Tags: css, image, html, background

I'm wanting to get an image overflowing a div, whilst not distrupting flow of text.

[image]

You can see it live at http://songbundle.org*

Example image above. Currently the text and form move right and lose their centering due to the image.

My current code below:

HTML:

```
<div class="box">
    <div id="boxarrow"></div>
    <p>text goes here</p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.box {
    margin:60px auto 0 auto; 
    width:240px; 
    border:solid 1px #7889BC; 
    background-color: #AEB8D7; 
    text-align:center;
}
#boxarrow {
    background:url(image/arrow.png); 
    width:77px; 
    height:81px; 
    display:block; 
    margin-left:-60px; 
    float:left;
}
```

Your help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hey there,

One solution you could try would be to apply `position: relative;` to your `.box` element and `position: absolute;` to your `#boxarrow` element. This will take the `#boxarrow` element out of the normal flow of the document, leaving other elements unaffected by its positioning.

Then, you can adjust it's position (relative to the `.box` element, since we gave it `position: relative;`) with `top`, `right`, `left`, and `bottom`. So, your `#boxarrow` element might end up looking something like this:

```css
#boxarrow {
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  left: 20px;
}
```

Again, this is just one possible solution, but it seems as though it would work best considering your situation.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

remove

```
margin-left:-60px; float:left;
```

from your #boxarrow and add

```
left:-60px; position:absolute;
```

Then add

```
position:relative;
```

to your .box

Final result:

```
.box {
  background-color: #AEB8D7;
  border: 1px solid #7889BC;
  margin: 60px auto 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  width: 240px;
}
#boxarrow {
  background: url("image/arrow.png");
  display: block;
  height: 81px;
  left: -60px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 77px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks man, that was exactly what I needed. Thanks to whoever put the picture in too! Oh yeh, and thanks to whoever it was signed up to the newsletter!

Answer (score 0):

Just change the positioning to absolute like this...

```
#boxarrow {background:url(image/arrow.png); width:77px; height:81px; display:block; margin-left:-60px; float:left;position: absolute;}
```